Inner join in exposed SQL
I have table which has trains current location and another table which station details
object Train:Table("Train"){
    val numb = integer("no")
    val name= varchar("name", length = 40)
    val cStnCode =varchar("cSC", length = 10).references(Stations.code)
    val delay = integer("dly")
    val srcCode = varchar("sC", length = 10).references(Stations.code)
    val destCode = varchar("dC", length = 10).references(Stations.code)
     val startDay = varchar("sD", length = 12)
     override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(numb, startDay)
}
object Stations:Table("Stations"){
    val name= varchar("name", length = 50)
    val code= varchar("code", length = 20)
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(code)
}

How could I get station name corresponding to code.
query i wrote is giving error: there is multiple primary key - foreign key references.
db.dbQuery {
            (Train innerJoin Stations)
                .select {
                (Train.cStnCode eq Stations.code)
                        (Train.srcCode eq Stations.code) and
                        (Train.destCode eq Stations.code)
            }
            .map {row->
                TrainClass(
                no = row[Train.numb],
                na = row[Train.name],
                cStC = row[Train.cStnCode],
                cStN = row[Stations.name], // Station name from join
                dly = row[Train.delay],
                sC = row[Train.srcCode],
                sN = "row[Stations.name]", // Station name from join
                dC = row[Train.destCode],
                dN = "row[Stations.name]", // Station name from join
}
}

If i am removing references then I get only one station name, where refernce is.
How can i get all three station names from Station table

You can use Aliases so that each join treats stations independently

Define alias for stations for each reference in train
Join train with alias based on foreign key relationship
retrieve all relevent fields from train and each aliased stations

for each row  in the result [we can put it in an instance of trainclass]
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction

object Train : Table("Train") {
    val numb = integer("no")
    val name = varchar("name", length = 40)
    val cStnCode = varchar("cSC", length = 10).references(Stations.code)
    val delay = integer("dly")
    val srcCode = varchar("sC", length = 10).references(Stations.code)
    val destCode = varchar("dC", length = 10).references(Stations.code)
    val startDay = varchar("sD", length = 12)
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(numb, startDay)
}

object Stations : Table("Stations") {
    val name = varchar("name", length = 50)
    val code = varchar("code", length = 20)
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(code)
}

// Data for train details
data class TrainClass(
    val no: Int,
    val na: String,
    val cStC: String,
    val cStN: String,
    val dly: Int,
    val sC: String,
    val sN: String,
    val dC: String,
    val dN: String
)

fun fetchTrainsWithStations() {
    transaction {
        // Alias for each foreign key relationship
        val currentStation = Stations.alias("currentStation")
        val sourceStation = Stations.alias("sourceStation")
        val destinationStation = Stations.alias("destinationStation")

        val query = Train.join(currentStation, JoinType.INNER, additionalConstraint = { Train.cStnCode eq currentStation[Stations.code] })
            .join(sourceStation, JoinType.INNER, additionalConstraint = { Train.srcCode eq sourceStation[Stations.code] })
            .join(destinationStation, JoinType.INNER, additionalConstraint = { Train.destCode eq destinationStation[Stations.code] })
            .selectAll()

        val result = query.map { row ->
            TrainClass(
                no = row[Train.numb],
                na = row[Train.name],
                cStC = row[Train.cStnCode],
                cStN = row[currentStation[Stations.name]], // Current station name from join
                dly = row[Train.delay],
                sC = row[Train.srcCode],
                sN = row[sourceStation[Stations.name]], // Source station name from join
                dC = row[Train.destCode],
                dN = row[destinationStation[Stations.name]] // Destination station name from join
            )
        }
        println(result)
    }
}



Hello, I have a question. Instead of getting the station name from the Stations table, I could have stored it in Train table? What would u recommend/best practice? storing it or fetching it. This functions will be used hundreds of time.

It's hard to tell, depending on requirements like performance/integrity/usage...You can consider the advantages/issues of each solution. Don't forget optimizations like [caching frequently accessed data in memory - you can access the information quickly and also keep the integrity of your source] [speed up your queries through foreign key indexing] ---- in general, data access patterns change over time, that's why fetching via join is advised to ensure normalization. if you have real-time requirements, redundant data/implementing caches can balance performance with data integrity
